# Problem with the zhnumber package

Tags: packages, cjk, xecjk

I am trying to write about numerals and the use of symbols. As an example I would like to use chinese/japanese symbols to show a multiplicative system. I have come up with the package `zhnumber` which works great for `\zhdigits` but not for `\zhnumber`. I have copied the examples from the documentation. Still I get the error: `Undefined control sequence`.
Can anyone please help? Is there something wrong with the combination of fonts or other packages? I am using a mac

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[norsk]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{STSong}
\usepackage{zhnumber}
\zhnumsetup{null,style=Traditional}

\begin{document}
\zhdigits{5} \\
\zhnumber{10}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: You shouldn't use inputenc with xelatex. Never.

Comment: And you shouldn't use `babel`. Use `polyglossia` when necessary. Don't use `fontenc` unless you know why.

Comment: @LeoLiu: babel is actively maintained and the author and the authors of the language packages are doing a lot to adapt it to the new engines. Depending on the language babel works fine with xelatex and lualatex and is often better than polyglossia.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I didn't know that. Since `polyglossia` now seems inactive, new `babel` may be better choice.

Comment: @LeoLiu: As I said: it depends on the language. It is not enough to have a sensible core package - someone must also create, maintain or adapt the language files. Also I don't know if polyglossia is really inactive. So imho one should decide depending on needs of the document.

Comment: Sorry about the first lines. That is what I usually use for my documents. I will look into what the fontenc does. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You don't say exactly what the undefined control sequence you get is, but I get the error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \__int_get_sign:n 
                             {10}\c_one 
l.13 \zhnumber{10}
```

with your example or a much shorter one

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{zhnumber}
\begin{document}
\zhdigits{5}
\end{document}
```

The `zhnumber` package is using an internal command from `expl3`, which it shouldn't. That particular internal has been removed, which is within the scope of what the LaTeX3 team can do with internal commands. As such, this is a bug in `zhnumber` and should be reported to the maintainer.

(I notice some other internal issues in that package, looking at the code. I will raise them with the author later today.)

Comment: Issue has been reported. to Qing Lee.

Comment: Any other internal issues? I find only one `\__` macro.

Comment: @LeoLiu Not bugs, more style things: for example,  take a look at the expandable status of a lot of the functions.

Comment: I use an internal function (`\__msg_expandable_error:n`) in the new version. I know it is not appropriate. But I really need it to function.

Comment: @QingLee That's one we've had some internal discussion about: please raise on LaTeX-L and make the case for a public interface

Answer (score 2):

This bug was fixed in the new version (v2.0) of `zhnumber`. I have submitted it to the CTAN. It is also to be updated in TeX Live.

Answer (score 1):

Before the new version of `zhnumber` is released, you can use this quick (and dirty) fix:

```
\documentclass[UTF8]{ctexart}

\usepackage[encoding=UTF8]{zhnumber}% v1.6 2012/11/23

% Quick fix
\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_set_nopar:Nn \zhnum_integer:n
  {
    \bool_set_false:N \my_isneg_bool
    \my_parse_signs:nw #1 \q_stop
    \zhnum_parse_number:f { \zhnum_trim_zeros:f { \zhnum_erase_separator:n {#1} } }
  }

\bool_new:N \my_isneg_bool

\cs_new_nopar:Npn \my_parse_signs:nw #1 #2 \q_stop
  {
    \tl_case:NnF #1
      {
        + { \my_parse_signs:nw #2 \q_stop }
        - {
            \bool_if:NTF \my_isneg_bool
              { \bool_set_false:N \my_isneg_bool }
              { \bool_set_true:N  \my_isneg_bool }
            \my_parse_signs:nw #2 \q_stop
          }
      }
      {
        \bool_if:NT \my_isneg_bool { \c_zhnum_minus_tl }
      }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\zhnumber{-1234567890123}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `\tl_case:NnF` be `\str_case:NnF`?

Comment: @egreg: What's the difference (in semantics or performance) here? I am not experienced in LaTeX3. And I guess there can be a better implementation of the whole `\zhnum_integer:n` macro.

Comment: The example doesn't compile for me, with `pdflatex`: `Package CJK Error: Invalid character code`

Comment: @egreg: Sorry, I tested it for XeTeX only. Using pdfTeX, `encoding` option must be specified: `\usepackage[encoding=UTF8]{zhnumber}`.

Comment: I added the code in my answer (that I will remove; you should be able to see it nonetheless).

Comment: @egreg: Thank you. The main problem seems that my code using `\tl_case:NnF` cannot handle empty string, which is rarely used. Anyway, since [Qing Lee](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/9521/qing-lee) has been informed by Joseph Wright, he will fix the issue, including the macro expansion problems. I think he would release a new version soon. See also [issue 161](https://code.google.com/p/ctex-kit/issues/detail?id=161#c1) in `ctex-kit` project (in Chinese).